# How to properly forward POST request from one web application to another in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, model-view-controller

Let's consider situation where I have two web application A and B

Initial data comes to A, where I have next controller:

```
@RestController
public class restController {
@RequestMapping(path = "/testA", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final void test(*inputdata*) { "redirect POST to B app" }
}
```

This data must be sent to app B:

```
@RestController
public class restController {
@RequestMapping(path = "/testB", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final void test(*inputdata*) { 'some logic' }
}
```

And result of logic must be sent back to A app.

Communication must happens in RESTful format.

As far as I found out by "googling" there is no way to do it by Spring and I must create custom "POST" method, is that true ? Because this link http://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward contains information about "Redirecting an HTTP POST Request" But I can't get the way they used it.

Thank you!

Comment: Are they Microservices?

Comment: @Mehraj Malik they are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RestTemplate](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) or [Feign Client](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html).

RestTemplate post example :

```
Foo foo = restTemplate.postForObject("/testB", request, Foo.class);
```

However, as you are using Microservices, you should use Feign client for microservices communication.

---

**Edit** :

Feign provides many extra benefits over RestTemplate.

Example: Feign client provides load balancing out of the box.

You can read more [here](http://javaonfly.blogspot.in/2017/07/microservices-communication-feign-as.html)

Comment: Thank you! Could you please elaborate - why should use exactly Feign ?

Comment: Mehraj Malik God bless you! Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

A `redirect` goes to the users browser and then goes to the redirected URL. It will always go as a `GET` request. In your case you will have to call app B from A using a `httpclient` (RestTemplate) from A. I am not sure whether that will satisfy your requirement. A

Another way could be to send a page as response from the A request and have the page submit a ajax request which is a POST to be, but I guess since you want everything on REST this may not be what you want.